# Why is there a memory leak at String creation in swift?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

The Leak is a **Root Leak**, In this image is being caused several times on the same line, but there is another below that is called single time and also produces a leak.

[image]

This is the call stack *after* calling the line of code stated before.

[image]

This is the class where the leak is located by Instruments:

```
class Item {
 var id: String!
 var name: String!

 internal init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.id = name
 }

 var description: String {
    return "(\(id)) \(name)"
 }
}
```

Leak is detected at line of computed variable **description** containing `return "(\(id)) \(name)"` and it gets solved after changing **description** into:

```
var description: String {
    return "(" + id + ") " + name
}
```

**Update:**

or

```
var description: String {
    if let id = self.id as? String, let name = self.name as? String {
        return "(\(id)) \(name)"
    }
    return "NO AVAILABLE DESCRIPTION"
}
```

> The last one emits a "Conditional cast from 'String!' to String always succeeds".
>
> So, even this looks like a hack.

**Why is this causing a leak?**

Comment: It is likely something outside this class that is causing the leak. Check the class that creates this Item object. Is it referencing id or name? 
Also, is the leak a "cycle? This also would indicate that something outside this class is holding a reference to it.

Comment: @Stephen I have updated the question, adding some insight of the leak

Comment: Both forms of the string concatenation should be valid.
It looks like this could be an Apple bug. You could try filing a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tested your code and gone through few threads and my understanding is that you have to optional binding `if let` clause, when using string interpolation instead of using optional variables directly. For String concatenation, if we use optionals directly there is no problem. The problem is with interpolation.

```
var description: String {
    if let id = self.id, let name = self.name {
        return "(\(id)) \(name)"
    }
    return "NO AVAILABLE DESCRIPTION"
}
```

You may get more info here [memory leak in Swift String interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897936/memory-leaks-when-using-optionals-in-string-interpolation).
Seems like a bug and may be in future release it will be solved.

Comment: This memory leak, incase of interpolation is happening for me if i am using more than one optional variable, with one it works good.

Comment: I tried your code, and even when my class' variables `id` and `name` are `String!` and Xcode states that "Conditional cast from 'String!' to String always succeeds" it compiles and stopped throwing such a leak.

Comment: I tested here, i am also getting same thing.

Comment: I added your hint into main question for better visibility, if no one can give me a better answer of exactly **"Why?"** this is happening  then the correct answer will be assigned to you. As I will assume that there is a bug, sadly I can't submit such a bug report myself.

Comment: Here is a bug report for a similar problem at [bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1728) if you want to check its status.