# Swift: How do I create a predicate with an Int value?

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6

I am getting an EXC-BAD-ACCESS error on this statement:

```
var thisPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(sectionNumber == %@"), thisSection)
```

thisSection has an Int value of 1  and displays the value 1 when I hover over it. But in the debug area I see this:

```
thisPredicate = (_ContiguousArrayStorage ...)
```

Another predicate using a String shows as ObjectiveC.NSObject
Why is this happening?

Comment: You have an extra opening parenthesis that should not be there

Comment: I'm not sure why it shows an extra parenthesis above because that is not what I have - which is:  var thisPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(sectionNumber == %@)",thisSection)

Comment: @PatriciaW the problem in your question was then that you missed the closure parenthesis after **@**. Btw, I have edited my previous answer, maybe you should take a look into some considerations I have added.

Comment: Hugo, I corrected my code in the comment above but I did not edit it ... which I will do now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When your data is safe or sanitized, you might try String Interpolation [Swift Standard Library Reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID292). That would look something like this:

```
let thisSection = 1
let thisPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "sectionNumber == \(thisSection)")
```

Comment: Please don't ever use String Interpolation when creating a predicate. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885149/543844, provided by Hugo Alonso should be selected as the correct answer.

Answer (score 46):

You will need to change `%@` for `%i` and remove the extra parenthesis:

Main problem here is that you are putting an `Int` where it's expecting an `String`.

Here's an example based on this [post](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/):

```
class Person: NSObject {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
}

let alice = Person(firstName: "Alice", lastName: "Smith", age: 24)
let bob = Person(firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Jones", age: 27)
let charlie = Person(firstName: "Charlie", lastName: "Smith", age: 33)
let quentin = Person(firstName: "Quentin", lastName: "Alberts", age: 31)
let people = [alice, bob, charlie, quentin]


let thisSection = 33
let thisPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "age == %i", thisSection)

let _people = (people as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(thisPredicate)
_people
```

Another workaround would be to make `thisSection`'s value an `String`, this can be achieved by **String Interpolation** or via `description` property of the `Int`.. lets say:

Changing:

```
let thisPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "age == %i", thisSection)
```

for

```
let thisPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "age == %@", thisSection.description)
```

or

```
let thisPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "age == %@", "\(thisSection)")
```

of course, you can always bypass this step and go for something more hardcoded (but also correct) as:

```
let thisPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "sectionNumber == \(thisSection)")
```

> But take into account that for some weird reason
>   **String Interpolation** (*this kind of structure:* `"\(thisSection)"`) where leading to retain cycles as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30039199/2683201)

Comment: Hugo, thanks for these suggestions. I tried %@ but did not know to use .description. I had tried %d but not %i.

Comment: `.description` is a property of every data type in **Swift**, it turns value of `Number`, `Date`, etc into it's `String` representation. `%i` do this conversion for you.

Comment: Spend two days to figure out why my fetchedresultcontroller with predicate isn't working, and the solution was replacing `%@` with `%i`. Data types are important, we need to make sure that we are filtering with the right type!!!

Comment: This won't work if the value is an int64 %I will convert treat it as an int32 and if the value is above 2,147,483,648 it will overflow.

Answer (score 2):

On 64 bit architecture an `Int` maps to an `Int64` and %i will overflow if its value is greater than 2,147,483,648.

You will need to change %@ for %ld and remove the extra parenthesis.

Comment: Then what should we use??

Comment: %ld. stackoverflow needs comments to be long so the rest of this is useless text