# Issue with fetching Core Data managed object using NSPredicate by object's enum attribute

Tags: swift, core-data, enums, nspredicate

I have an issue with fetching a Core Data managed object which has an `enum` attribute with `Int16` rawValues. The program crashes when calling `NSPredicate(format:)`.

This is the code (3rd line) that results a crash:

```
func returnBook (bookType: BookType) -> Book? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", #keyPath(Book.bookType), bookType.rawValue as CVarArg)
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    let book = (try? fetchRequest.execute())?.first
    return book
}
```

Crash message is:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3)

When I change the 3rd line with the following, I get another kind of error.

This is the alternative code:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", #keyPath(Book.bookType), bookType as! CVarArg)
```

And this is the error resulted by that alternative code:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

And I see this in the debug output:

> Could not cast value of type 'ProjectName.BookType' (0x10ac10098)
>   to 'Swift.CVarArg' (0x10b698548).

Here are some other related code in the Project:

```
@objc(Book)
public class Book: NSManagedObject {
    // …
}

extension Book {

    @NSManaged public var bookType: BookType

}

@objc public enum BookType: Int16 {
    case fiction    = 0
    case nonFiction = 1
    case reference  = 2
}
```

**My question:** How can I properly fetch the `Book` object from my Core Data store by using its `bookType` attribute, which is in an `@objc enum` type with `Int16` rawValues?

***Update:***

I have tried something else as suggested [in a presentation](https://github.com/jessesquires/talks/blob/master/2015/04-14%20Using%20Core%20Data%20in%20Swift/using_core_data_in_swift.md) by Jesse Squires:

1. Removed `@objc` keyword from `enum`'s definition
2. Used `private` and `public` properties to access the `enum`'s instances...

I have changed my code as suggested in the linked presentation, and I have changed the name of `bookType` attribute in Core Data's ".xcdatamodeld" file to `bookTypeValue`.

```
extension Book {

    public var bookType: BookType {
        get {
            return BookType(rawValue: self.bookTypeValue)!
        }
        set {
            self.bookTypeValue = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }

    @NSManaged private var bookTypeValue: Int16

}

public enum BookType: Int16 {
    case fiction    = 0
    case nonFiction = 1
    case reference  = 2
}
```

And I tried to fetch using the private value as suggested in the presentation linked above...:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bookTypeValue == %@", bookType)
```

However I could not solve my problem with this method either... XCode complains immediately:

> Argument type 'BookType' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'

XCode stops complaining if I use `bookType.rawValue` instead. However, program crashes during runtime with the same error above (first one).

***Update 2:***

I have applied the answers given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884863) which is suggested by the community. To be more specific, I have tried the suggestion in the answer to that question which is using `%i`, or `@ld` instead of `%@` like so:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bookTypeValue == %i", bookType.rawValue)
```

and I have tried the other suggestion which is using String interpolation like so:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bookTypeValue == %@", "\(bookType.rawValue)")
```

These code changes prevented crashes, but func `returnBook` returns nil, even if I am sure that the data is there. Fetch or comparison fails for some reason...

Comment: I guess bookType must be defined as Transformable in the model editor?  When you renamed it to bookTypeValue, did you change it to Integer?  Predicates do not work well for Transformable attributes (at least not when fetching).

Comment: @pbasdf bookType was defined as Int16 in the model editor (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31681870/3780985 ), and after I have renamed it to bookTypeValue, it remained the same in the model editor as Int16. I only changed its type in the code from BookType to Int16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this problem for many hours finally I have managed to solve it.

Here is what I have done to solve the problem in chronological order:

1. I have changed the type of `bookTypeValue` from `Int16` to `Int32`, because I could not see a format specifier for 16-bit integers in the official (archived) [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). I have tested and I can confirm that if you use `%@` here instead of correct format specifier, which is `%d` for signed 32-bit integers, you get the first error in the question:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3)

2. I have changed the `NSPredicate(format:)` call like so:

   fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bookTypeValue == %d", bookType.rawValue)
3. I have changed the 5th line in `returnBook` func like so:

   ```
    do {
       let results = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
       if results.count > 0 {
           book = results.first
           return book
       } 
    } catch let error as NSError {
       print("Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
    }
   ```